# How to put on a car cover in the rain?

Tags: long-term-storage

I have a vintage car that I only drive once a month or so. I live in a very rainy area, so it is extremely unlikely to not be raining, even most of the year.

I was thinking I could wash the dirt off with a sponge after driving, try to dry it as quickly as I can with a towel, then throw the cover on and hope the underside of the cover dries without mildewing.

Unfortunately a garage is out of the question as I am a renter.

Any ideas? Is it ok to put the cover on a damp car? Maybe there is some idea I haven't thought of?

Thanks!

Comment: I've been in this situation myself and found that I was still able to access a garage.  One way I did this was to place an advert locally and was able to rent the space in a neighbours double garage.  Another was I approached the local council who had a number of garages within walking distance I could rent.

Answer (score 1):

You should use car cover to protect it from daily dust,tree sap,bird's poop and of course the rain water.But one thing to remember is that the car should be dry.If you cover a damp car with a cover the water trapped inside would never dry and may affect the car's paint bad instead of doing good.

You should not cover a wet car as the trapped water might cause formation of  mold and can also leave water marks on the paints surface.

Solution:
What i would suggest you instead is that you should instead apply good quality wax polish(carnuba wax) on the car's body(of course the car needs to be little bit of damp for polish to spread properly). Wax is a water repellent would not allow the water to stay on the car's surface and would also protect the car's paint.And the day when your car is dry then you can cover it up with a car cover properly tying up all the strings.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should apple wax first and than when you drive try to cover most of your car while you are driving so it will be dry.

*emphasized text*

Comment: Stop to have it

Comment: Maybe bring the car first to a shaded area than apply wax on it so the paint will not get damaged and clean your car while under shade. Then after, when you drive your car try to cover most of your car but make sure you don’t cover the whole car so you can see through the windshield. Than when you park your car try to dry as fast than cover the car right away after the car is dry.

Comment: please edit the additional information into the answer and not into the comments.